# Separate info from an array with to make a comma separated string

Tags: php, arrays, arraylist

I want to make a string separated by a comma.
Example :
test, sdf

```
Array ( 
[0] => Array ( [name] => Test [0] => Test ) 
[1] => Array ( [name] => sdf [0] => sdf ) )
```

```
$List = implode(', ', $Array);
```

Return : Notice: Array to string conversion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extract the list of arrays into another array, then perform the implode

[Demo](https://onlinephp.io/c/503d3)

```
<?php
$Array=[];

$temparray= ["name" => "Test" ];
array_push($Array,$temparray );

$temparray= ["name" => "sdf" ];
array_push($Array,$temparray );

//print_r($Array);

foreach($Array as $key=>$value) {
$newarray[]=$value["name"];
}
$List = implode(', ', $newarray);
var_dump($List);
?>
```